# How to get names of all colorscales in plotly?

Tags: python, r, plotly

I was wondering how to get all the names of available colorscales in plotly in a list.

Wanted:

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.tools as tls
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=False)

colorscales = plotly.something.something

import plotly.graph_objs as go
x = ['Albania', 'Denmark', 'France', 'Finland', 'USSR']
y = [4, 2, 3, 5, 9]
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=[go.Bar(x=x, y=y,
                                 marker={'color': y,
                                               'colorscale': 'Viridis'})]) 
fig
```

Here I want to replace 'Viridis' by colorscales[0] and choose whatever colormap it gives.

Comment: Did you check out this discussion?  https://community.plot.ly/t/what-colorscales-are-available-in-plotly-and-which-are-the-default/2079

Comment: @DavidKlotz Yes I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the individual colorscale name by using the `inspect` module while iterating over the known color modules:

```
import inspect

colorscale_names = []
colors_modules = ['carto', 'colorbrewer', 'cmocean', 'cyclical',
                    'diverging', 'plotlyjs', 'qualitative', 'sequential']
for color_module in colors_modules:
    colorscale_names.extend([name for name, body
                            in inspect.getmembers(getattr(px.colors, color_module))
                            if isinstance(body, list)])
```

All the names are now available in the list `colorscale_names` (including those from `PLOTLY_SCALES` since they are replicated in the color modules). There are some duplicates, which you could remove by casting it to a set.

Here are all the names printed in columns.

```
from textwrap import fill

print(fill(''.join(sorted({f'{x: <{15}}' for x in colorscale_names})), 75))
```

```
Accent         Aggrnyl        Agsunset       Alphabet       Antique
Armyrose       Blackbody      Bluered        Blues          Blugrn
Bluyl          Bold           BrBG           Brwnyl         BuGn
BuPu           Burg           Burgyl         Cividis        D3
Dark2          Dark24         Darkmint       Earth          Edge
Electric       Emrld          Fall           G10            Geyser
GnBu           Greens         Greys          HSV            Hot
IceFire        Inferno        Jet            Light24        Magenta
Magma          Mint           OrRd           Oranges        Oryel
PRGn           Paired         Pastel         Pastel1        Pastel2
Peach          Phase          PiYG           Picnic         Pinkyl
Plasma         Plotly         Plotly3        Portland       Prism
PuBu           PuBuGn         PuOr           PuRd           Purp
Purples        Purpor         Rainbow        RdBu           RdGy
RdPu           RdYlBu         RdYlGn         Redor          Reds
Safe           Set1           Set2           Set3           Spectral
Sunset         Sunsetdark     T10            Teal           Tealgrn
Tealrose       Temps          Tropic         Twilight       Viridis
Vivid          YlGn           YlGnBu         YlOrBr         YlOrRd
algae          amp            balance        curl           deep
delta          dense          gray           haline         ice
matter         mrybm          mygbm          oxy            phase
scale_pairs    scale_sequence solar          speed          tempo
thermal        turbid
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: there is now a dedicated documentation page for this, including swatches at https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/

---

[This file](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/65625d49226632abcf932d530aa9c90ba1bc59c1/packages/python/plotly/_plotly_utils/colors/__init__.py) contains most of what you’re looking for.

So probably `from plotly._plotly_utils.colors import PLOTLY_SCALES` will allow you to do `colorscales = PLOTLY_SCALES.keys()` although this is meant to be an internal object.

I should add that there are other color scales that Plotly will recognize by name but those aren’t available as a neat import like this as they are in other modules like `plotly.express.colors.sequential` or `plotly.express.colors.cyclical` etc.

Comment: Note that that plotly builtin-colorscales documentation page only lists colorscales for Express and Dash, but does not list the coloscales available with the "go" API. :-(  For example, in Plotly Express "px" the colorscale "turbo" exists, but it is not defined in the "go" version of Plotly.

Comment: That's actually not correct: Express and Graph Objects share the same set of color scales. Turbo works fine for both (although it was introduced only recently so be sure to upgrade to the latest version!)

Comment: "only recently" must be in the past few days then. I was literally just getting error messages that turbo was not defined as part of go-plotly, and I pip-installed plotly three days ago.

Comment: Added in 4.13 on Nov 11, 2020: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#4130---2020-11-23 ... This code runs for me in 4.14.3:  `go.Figure(go.Scatter(mode="markers",y=[1,2,3,4],marker_color=[1,2,3,4],marker_colorscale="turbo"))`

Answer (score 1):

The following are all colorscales in plotly

```
['aggrnyl', 'agsunset', 'algae', 'amp', 'armyrose', 'balance',
'blackbody', 'bluered', 'blues', 'blugrn', 'bluyl', 'brbg',
'brwnyl', 'bugn', 'bupu', 'burg', 'burgyl', 'cividis', 'curl',
'darkmint', 'deep', 'delta', 'dense', 'earth', 'edge', 'electric',
'emrld', 'fall', 'geyser', 'gnbu', 'gray', 'greens', 'greys',
'haline', 'hot', 'hsv', 'ice', 'icefire', 'inferno', 'jet',
'magenta', 'magma', 'matter', 'mint', 'mrybm', 'mygbm', 'oranges',
'orrd', 'oryel', 'peach', 'phase', 'picnic', 'pinkyl', 'piyg',
'plasma', 'plotly3', 'portland', 'prgn', 'pubu', 'pubugn', 'puor',
'purd', 'purp', 'purples', 'purpor', 'rainbow', 'rdbu', 'rdgy',
'rdpu', 'rdylbu', 'rdylgn', 'redor', 'reds', 'solar', 'spectral',
'speed', 'sunset', 'sunsetdark', 'teal', 'tealgrn', 'tealrose',
'tempo', 'temps', 'thermal', 'tropic', 'turbid', 'twilight',
'viridis', 'ylgn', 'ylgnbu', 'ylorbr', 'ylorrd']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware how to get all the names in a single list but what I usually do is make a typo in `colorscale` name e.g. `Viridis1` instead of `Viridis`, then look at the error messages and copy the list of available colorscales.

Its not the best way to do it, but it works.